# Constant angles and powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

One can verify without difficulty that for all triple $(a,b,c)$ of real numbers greater than $1$, with $a\le b\le c$, and for all positive integer $n$, the equality
$$a^n+b^n=c^n\qquad (*)$$ ►it has infinitely many solutions;

► with segments of lengths $a,b,c$  one can build a triangle.

Furthermore, the angle $\widehat C$ opposed to the side $c$ is constant for $n=1$ and $n=2$ (respectively $\widehat C=\pi$ and $\widehat C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ the case $n=1$ corresponding to “degenerate” triangles).

**(1)** Prove that for $n\gt 2$ this property of constant angles is no longer valid and  $$\frac{\pi}{3}\lt \widehat C\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$$ 
**(2)** Are there distinct non-proportional triples $(a,b,c)$ and $(a_1,b_1,c_1)$  solutions of $(*)$ having the same angle $\widehat C$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

Assume that
$a \le b$.

For angle $C$,
use the cosine formula.

If
$a^n+b^n
= c^n
$,
then
$c 
=(a^n+b^n)^{1/n}
=b(1+(a/b)^n)^{1/n}
\le b(1+\frac{a^n}{nb^n})
\le b(1+\frac{1}{n})
$.

To show that
$a, b, c$
make a triangle,
you have to show that
$a+b > c$,
or
$a+b
> (a^n+b^n)^{1/n}
$.
This should be easy.